# Calculate the double integral $\iint x + y\; dxdy$ over the ellipse segment

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the double integral:

$$\iint (x + y)dxdy$$ over the ellipse segment $4x^2 + y^2 \le 9$, in the first quadrant.

Comment: Consider the coordinate change $x = \tfrac{r}2\cos\theta$ and $y = r \sin\theta$...

Comment: I found the limits for y to be 0 to 3, and limits of x to be 0 to 3/2, can anyone confirm this?